# Why is the parameter value an Object hash code for `request.getParameterMap().get(name)`

Tags: java, servlets

Why is the parameter value an Object hash code:

```
input_name:[[Ljava.lang.String;@3f4d64]
```

I thought the code `request.getParameterMap().get(name);` would produce the value of the request parameter:

```
    Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
    while(params.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String name = (String)params.nextElement(); 
        String value = request.getParameterMap().get(name);
        logger.log(name + ": " + value);
    }
```

Comment: This code would not have compiled. I think you originally used `Object value`. In the future, please take care that you're posting the *actual* code, to avoid red herrings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it returns a `String[]`, not a `String`. The javadoc of [`getParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) also tells that:

> #### Returns:
>
> an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are of type String. **The values in the parameter map are of type String array.**

So you need to treat it as an array. If you'd like to obtain a single (the first) parameter value, use [`request.getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) instead. Here's a rewrite:

```
for (String name : Collections.<String>list(request.getParameterNames())) {
    String value = request.getParameter(name); 
    logger.log(name + ": " + value);
}
```

Or if you really want to check all possible parameter values, then just iterate over the map's entryset:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    String[] values = entry.getValue();
    logger.log(name + ": " + Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a question about the first code block above. The Collections.list part produces the error: "Cannot convert from element Object to type String". Is there a cast needed somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it was not parameterized, I fixed the code.

Comment: How to get only specified parameters, eg: `http://localhost:8080/project/?pid=1&cid=20&start=1&end=24&uid=9`. If I want to get only `pid` and `cid`, how can I get only this attributes using `getParameterMap()`

Answer (score 6):

The parameter map is a map from parameter names to arrays of values. This is because you may have multiple values for the same parameter. Consider for instance the following request:

`http://www.example.com/var=value1&var=value2`

In this case you would get `{ "value1", "value2" }` when getting the parameters for `var`.

If you want to print all values for a given parameter, you could use [`Arrays.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) on the array of values.

If you know that each variable has at most one value, you could use [`getParameter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). From the docs:

> *You should only use this method when you are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).*

Comment: Kudos for explaining the 'why'. As usual, "other programmers" are the reason we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `HttpServletRequest` have

```
Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
```

is because of Form Submit that have the same parameter names but different values. You can essentially have a URL form with 1 or more same parameter names with different values.

See *BalusC* response.